# Gparted Shows HDD as unallocated

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, gparted, gpt

I've **Windows 8.1** & I'm planning to install **Kali Linux** with it.

However, at installation `gparted` shows the whole hard disk to be unallocated and a warning.

The warning is as follows:

> /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?

`gdisk` can read my partitions from the `mbr` but not from the `gpt`.

Here is what is shows:

```
root@kali:~# sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 1
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): ED648B30-B2CA-4C17-875F-3BB5BE8015E5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 205600109 sectors (98.0 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2050047   1000.0 MiB  0700  Microsoft basic data
   2         2582528         4630527   1000.0 MiB  0700  Microsoft basic data
   5         4892672       982384639   466.1 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   6       982386688      1748723711   365.4 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data

root@kali:~# sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 2
Using GPT and creating fresh protective MBR.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F2A030D1-94C2-4592-9DFA-D227C1615693
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1953525101 sectors (931.5 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

**PS** : I've tried using gdisk's option `f -"load MBR and build fresh GPT"` from the "`recovery/transformation options`".

However, it was of no use as `gparted` shows the same thing.

Comment: Don't forget to back all your documents up before repartitioning.  You may be able to back them up to Google Drive or DropBox (for free) or to a USB stick.  Have you tried running GParted from a Ubuntu live CD?  Did it work?

Comment: Tried using Ubuntu as well, gparted couldn't recognise my hardisk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a recent version of GParted (currently the latest version is 0.23.0)?

GParted uses the libparted library from the parted project to detect and manipulate partitions.  In your situation it appears that both an MSDOS and a GUID Partition Table exist.  You might try running parted directly from the command line:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda
```

and instructing parted to use only the GPT with a protective MBR.